# Why is E2 reactivity rate of 1-iodo-1-methylcyclohexane faster than (1R,2S)-1-iodo-2-methylcyclohexane even though the transition state is same?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image]

Why is E2 reactivity rate of the second compound said to be faster than the first compound even though the transition state is same? My teacher said that in E2 more hindrance implies faster reaction. In the first compound H atom is more hindered due to methyl group. Even then why is the reactivity of the second compound in presence of a strong base, said to be faster?

Comment: See: [E1 and E2 elimination reactions of isotopically labeled bromocyclohexanes](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/46786/16683)

Comment: If the rates are different, the transition state must be different, no?

Comment: Why do you think the transition states are identical? The connectivity is different...